# Differential Equation help

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have a differential equation that looks like this:

```
 DSolve[(D[R[r, t], t])^2/(2*c) - (G*M1[r, z])/(
   c^2*R[r, t]) - (λ*(R[r, t])^2)/3 - E1[r] == 0, ... "boundary conditions etc go here"]
```

I need to get `R[r, t]` using my values of `E1[r]` and `M1[r]`. However, my `M1[r]` is defined as:

```
M1[r_] :=  NIntegrate[(1 + f*Exp[-(r/y)^2])*(r)^2, r]
```

Herein lies the problem. I realise that `DSolve` uses `Integrate` internally, but the function I want it to solve has an `NIntegrate` in it and this causes problems. I'm not sure how else to evaluate an error function.

Any ideas?

Comment: This gives a solution in terms of an unresolved integral. Eventually. `DSolve[(D[R[r, t], t])^2/(2*c) - (G*M1[r, z])/(c^2*
      R[r, t]) - (\[Lambda]*(R[r, t])^2)/3 - E1[r] == 0, R[r, t], t]`

Comment: What is the definition of `f` in your function `M1[r_]`? a unknown function?

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing what the actual differential equation is, I can only point out one obvious problem: you should define

```
Clear[r,f,y];
M1[r_] = Integrate[(1 + f*Exp[-(r/y)^2])*(r)^2, r]
```

instead of using `:= NIntegrate` because you seem to be looking for an indefinite integral there. For numerical integration you have to specify integration limits. The `Clear` is just added for safety before I define the function with `=` so that the integral will be done at that time, once and for all.

Comment: Wrapping the integral in `Block[{r,f,y}, ...]` would work, also, and limit the impact on the rest of the notebook.

Comment: For all I know, `f` in the question could in fact have a value - so it may be a moot point...

Comment: True, very true.